# Problem with limit and exponent together

Tags: math-mode

[image]

How to write **exp(lim x-> infinity 2/x )** in proper way , the limit range should come below **lim**, and everything to the power of **e**.

```
e^{\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2}{x} \cdot x}
```

How to modify this code to get the desired output.

Comment: Use  `\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}`.

Comment: Actually it should not, as the `lim` part should then be much larger than `e^x`. I'd suggest  writing this as `\exp(....)` instead. Also the `\over` syntax is not used in LaTeX.

Comment: Additionally why is this tagged with `tikz-pgf`

Comment: I have added the image please check

Comment: I have added Tikz if some work around is available anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some options, ranked IMNSHO from best to worst. In all cases, `x\to\infty` is placed *below* `\lim`, as stipulated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \tfrac and \text macros
\begin{document}
\[
\exp\bigl(\lim_{x\to\infty}\tfrac{2}{x}\cdot x\bigr)
\quad\text{vs}\quad
\exp\Bigl(\,\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2}{x}\cdot x\Bigr)
\quad\text{vs}\quad
e^{\bigl(\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(2/x)\cdot x\bigr)}
\quad\text{vs}\quad
e^{\bigl(\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2}{x}\cdot x\bigr)}
\]
\end{document}
```